# Execution of a piece of code several times

Tags: android, gps, sms

I am developing an app where I want to send an SMS just once and when the bluetoothspeed value is changed and exceeded.
This is the code that I am using - it sends the SMS each time the bluetoothspeed+30 value is exceeded

```
  if (GPSspeed > bluetoothSpeed+30) { if (!malreadyExecuted) {
                           Log.d("malreadyExecuted", " in if block is = " + String.valueOf(malreadyExecuted));
                           sendsms();
                           malreadyExecuted = true;}}

                           malreadyExecuted = false ;}
```

Comment: you forgot to tell us what is the problem.

Comment: the problem is i want the sms to be sent just once when the gpsspeed is higher then bluetoothspeed+30 then when i change the bluetoothspeed value the sms should be send one time and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are setting malreadyExecuted false. If in next line then it will not work.

Comment: Ok, if you are setting it false after if block, then it is wrong.

Comment: i set it false in order to send the SMS every time the bluetoothspeed change and it works ; now i want it to be sent just once when the GPSspeed exceed the bluetoothspeed+30 value

Comment: I want to check complete if else block you are using now. Definitely there is some logical error as you mentioned it was working fine earlier.

Comment: try {
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(cmd).useDelimiter("[^0-9]+");
                    bluetoothSpeed = in.nextInt();
                    if (GPSspeed > bluetoothSpeed && (bluetoothSpeed != lastBluetoothSpeed || GPSspeed != lastGPSspeed)) {
                        lastBluetoothSpeed = bluetoothSpeed;
                        lastGPSspeed = GPSspeed;
                        lastBluetoothTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
                        }

Comment: else if (bluetoothSpeed != lastBluetoothSpeed) {
                        lastBluetoothSpeed = bluetoothSpeed;
                    } else if (lastBluetoothSpeed != -1 && GPSspeed > lastBluetoothSpeed && GPSspeed != lastGPSspeed) {
                        lastBluetoothTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;

Comment: if (GPSspeed > bluetoothSpeed+30) { if(bluetoothSpeed != lastBluetoothSpeed){ if (!malreadyExecuted) {
                           Log.d("malreadyExecuted", " in if block is = " + String.valueOf(malreadyExecuted));
                           sendsms();
                            malreadyExecuted = true;}}}
                        malreadyExecuted = false;

Comment: those  are my if and else if blocks